# Using phrase query with PreAnalyzedField in solr 4

Tags: solr

i am using solr 4.0, i trying running phrase query like text:"the fox" and i dont get answer from solr. I index the field using dynamic field (*_S) with field type pre analyzed field (PreAnalyzedField).
I using json format with tokens positions information to index the field. Does anyone know why phrase query not working? may be it related to PreAnalyzedField?
I try using field attribute like autoGeneratePhraseQueries="false" but solr not like it...
thank you.

Comment: Can you provide the field defintion from your schema and show an example of your input data?

Answer (score 0):

This may be late but in case you are still looking using omitPositions =false or omitTermFreqAndPositions =false will store the term positions and phrase query work.

Fields which are not storing positions phrase query will not work.